# In Ubuntu 15.04 the sound settings no longer work as they did in 13.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, 15.04

I have no idea what is going on but my sound settings now no longer work properly in 15.04. I firstly upgraded to 14.04 and then to 15.04. Before I had sound control buttons on the very top status bar, they are no gone. And, the auto-mute used to work when I plugged in my headphones before, now that no longer works either. And to top it all off, the sound settings GUI in System settings is opaque which means I cannot see it properly. What is going wrong here people?!! Not happy with THIS upgrade at all.

Comment: Is it working correctly from a live DvD/USB of 15.04? It may be easier to do a fresh install than fixing whatever messed up.

Comment: OK, run `alsamixer` in terminal. Typically if I want to set/unset auto-mute, i go there. As for the sound control indicator, it works in my ubuntu install, but as of 15.04 it doesn't work in `openbox` desktop for me, so i got `volti`. Pretty much that's the same thing as sound indicator.

Answer (score 0):

its a permission issue, it happened with me as well.
on ubuntu 14.04.
open terminal and run

```
sudo rm -r ~/.config/pulse
```

and force reload alsa

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

it should be fixed now.

Comment: Too late, i ended up going Back two versions instead. Running 12.04 until 2016.